# Rotating algorithm for sets of selected features and getting the result into a single layer instead of a unique layer for each output

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Ive written the rotating algorithm to rotate a selected set of points on each iteration, what I'm trying to accomplish is to aggregate the output into one final layer, instead of having multiple outputs per each set of selected points (i.e each iteration).

```
for cell in GetUniqueList(square_layer, 'global_cel'):
    layer.selectByExpression('"CELLKEY"={}'.format(cell))
    feat = layer.selectedFeatures()[0]
    azimuth = feat['predicted_']
    lat = feat['latitude_1']
    long = feat['longitud_1']
    center_coords = ConvertCrs(long, lat)
    
    params = {'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id(), selectedFeaturesOnly=True),
    'ANGLE':-azimuth,'ANCHOR':center_coords,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
    rotate = processing.run("native:rotatefeatures", params)

    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([rotate['OUTPUT']])
    
layer.removeSelection()
```

Comment: Can you merge them?  `processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[a, list, of, all, layers],'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})`

Comment: No, im trying to avoid loading each layer as there's alot of them, Im looking for something more like an append all the output features into the new layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of merging all layers at the end, you can create a layer to collect all rotated features, appending them as they are processed.

Something similar to this (*untested, as the code seems to refer to unpublished functions*):

```
collectorLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Points", 'Collector layer', "memory") 
dp = collectorLayer.dataProvider()
# define the fields of collectorLayer
dp.addAttributes([ QgsField("ID", QVariant.String), QgsField("predicted_", QVariant.String), QgsField("latitude_1", QVariant.String), QgsField("longitud_1", QVariant.String)])


for cell in GetUniqueList(square_layer, 'global_cel'):
    layer.selectByExpression('"CELLKEY"={}'.format(cell))
    feat = layer.selectedFeatures()[0]
    azimuth = feat['predicted_']
    lat = feat['latitude_1']
    long = feat['longitud_1']
    center_coords = ConvertCrs(long, lat)
    
    params = {'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id(), selectedFeaturesOnly=True),
    'ANGLE':-azimuth,'ANCHOR':center_coords,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
    rotated = processing.run("native:rotatefeatures", params)
    
    for rotated_feat in rotated['OUTPUT'].getFeatures():
        dp.addFeatures([rotated_feat])
    
    #QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([rotate['OUTPUT']])
    layer.removeSelection()

collectorLayer.updateExtents()
collectorLayer.updateFields()
```

(I assumed your input files are of type `Point`, by the way)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was what i needed. Just a minor change needed here is that
rotated.getFeatures() need to be changed into rotated['OUTPUT'].getFeatures() 
as the variable rotated is a dict and not a vectorlayer. I'm sure you knew. Ill add it here for reference. Thank you very much